# "Вы достигли Вашей цели" или "... Вашу цель"?

Tags: глаголы

Мой навигатор (если это важно -- Navigon) в русской озвучке при завершении маршрута говорит фразу "Вы достигли Вашей цели". С одной стороны, конечно, это логично -- достичь ЧЕГО? Но фраза "он достиг своей цели" звучит для меня совершенно корректно, однако я понимаю её только в значении "достичь того, что хотел получить" (например получить образование, построить дом).

Относительно места назначения я бы сказал "Вы достигли Вашу цель".

Что в данном случае является более корректным и какую фразу следует предпочесть?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Глагол `достичь` непереходный, управляет родительным падежом, это отмечено в любом нормальном словаре, например [у Ожегова](http://www.ozhegov.org/words/7673.shtml), ни о каком винительном падеже после него и речи быть не может, только `Вы достигли Вашей цели`, это единственно правильный вариант падежа.

К чему тут ещё можно придраться, так это к слову `Вашей`, по-русски обычно говорят `Вы достигли своей цели`.

Answer (score 7):

В данном случае, слово "цель" не очень подходит: так лучше переводить английские "goal", "purpose", или "objective". "Destination" тоже подходит как одно из значений, но "вы прибыли в пункт назначения" звучит предпочтительнее, чем "Вы достигли вашей цели".

Comment: Именно! Навигатор должен говорить: "прибыли", "слезайте, приехали", или "докатились!" - но никак не о целях.

Comment: _"Слезайте, граждане, приехали, конец."_

Comment: согласен. это просто дословный перевод с английского. но так не говорят. "вы прибыли в пункт назначения" - отличный вариант!